# Xcode iPhone - How To Attach A Signature To A Text Message Automatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sms

What I am trying to figure out how to do is, when I send a regular text message through my iPhone's built in text messaging app, how can I hard-code a text message (signature) to be displayed after my text message I write to someone?

Example:

1. I launch my text messaging app, and I want to send a text to someone named John.
2. I then type the following to John in the text field: "Hello John, how are you?"
3. After I press the send button, I see the standard bubble, but below my text I sent to John is my hard coded signature.

So it sent my original text as well as my hard coded signature to John. So what exactly do I need to do "code wise" in order to accomplish this? **Example code would be great if possible**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution—iOS doesn't allow you to automate the sending of text messages (to prevent spamming and/or junk messages). However, you can present an interface through [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

In this class there is a `body` property. By setting an `NSString` to that property, you can present existing text. Of course the user would still work around that, and could delete it—that is something you have no control over, for UX reasons.

Comment: Well I guess what I'm saying is, the user would be aware of this happening. They would download my app, and the app would have this feature built in and the user wouldn't have to do anything different than what they were already doing when sending text messages. Does that make sense?

Comment: Apple doesn't know this, of course, and there still does not exist the API to do so. The best you can do is pre-populate the message field and hope the user doesn't change it.